# replace lines with lines from another text file by matching patterns

Tags: regex, perl, sed, awk, pattern-matching

I have a file file_pattern like this:

```
SET  default_parallel 10
SET  pig.splitCombination true
SET  pig.maxCombinedSplitSize 134217728
register 'hdfs:///usr/lib/pig/piggybank.jar'; 
define LENGTH org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.string.LENGTH();

//Some other stuff goes here
```

and another file insert_file like this:

```
ld_DW_D_INSTALLATION_PRODUCTS = load '/dan/data/dwh/dw_d_installation_products' using PigStorage ('|') as (inst_prod_wid , bac_wid , di
strict_code , billing_account_no , inst_sequence_no , product_code , contract_type , maintenance_contract , exchange_line_indicator , p
roduct_type , quantity , first_cph_date , last_cph_date , first_cph_term_expiry_date , last_cph_term_expiry_date , last_cph_order_no ,
ts_last_updated , data_owner , source_system , etl_created_dt);
ld_DEDUP_PROD_TPC_EXTRACT = load '/dan/data/dedup/dedup_prod_tpc_extract' using PigStorage ('|') as ( productfamilyid , productfamily ,
 productgroupid , productgroup , grouplobid , productgroupowninglob , newproductid , newproductname , productowner , lifecycleid , life
cycle , buildgroupid , buildgroupname , ukbreleaseno , gs_productbuildstatusid , gs_productbuildstatus , ab_code , ab_codename , codelo
bid , codeowninglob , ab_codedestinyid , ab_codedestiny , ab_code_treatmentid , ab_code_treatmentstatus , gs_mappingstatusid , gs_mappi
ngstatus , consumercount , btb_count , gs_count , otherbu_count , operateflagid , operateflagdescription , withdrawalprojectid , withdr
awalproject , line_type , note );
```

Now i want a script which will give me output like this:

```
SET  default_parallel 10
SET  pig.splitCombination true
SET  pig.maxCombinedSplitSize 134217728

ld_DW_D_INSTALLATION_PRODUCTS = load '/dan/data/dwh/dw_d_installation_products' using PigStorage ('|') as (inst_prod_wid , bac_wid , di
strict_code , billing_account_no , inst_sequence_no , product_code , contract_type , maintenance_contract , exchange_line_indicator , p
roduct_type , quantity , first_cph_date , last_cph_date , first_cph_term_expiry_date , last_cph_term_expiry_date , last_cph_order_no ,
ts_last_updated , data_owner , source_system , etl_created_dt);
ld_DEDUP_PROD_TPC_EXTRACT = load '/dan/data/dedup/dedup_prod_tpc_extract' using PigStorage ('|') as ( productfamilyid , productfamily ,
 productgroupid , productgroup , grouplobid , productgroupowninglob , newproductid , newproductname , productowner , lifecycleid , life
cycle , buildgroupid , buildgroupname , ukbreleaseno , gs_productbuildstatusid , gs_productbuildstatus , ab_code , ab_codename , codelo
bid , codeowninglob , ab_codedestinyid , ab_codedestiny , ab_code_treatmentid , ab_code_treatmentstatus , gs_mappingstatusid , gs_mappi
ngstatus , consumercount , btb_count , gs_count , otherbu_count , operateflagid , operateflagdescription , withdrawalprojectid , withdr
awalproject , line_type , note );
```

Overall what i want is second file should be inserted after the last occurrence of SET statement.

Thanks in advance
Raghavendra

Comment: I found the answer for this using sed:
skip_set=10
sed "${skip_set}r file_to_insert" input_file

it will insert content of file_to_insert after 10th line of input_file

Answer (score 2):

Code for GNU [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
$sed -r '/^SET/H;$bk;d;:k;x;s#.*\n(.*)\'#/\1/{\na\nr file2\n}#' file1|sed -f - file1
SET  default_parallel 10
SET  pig.splitCombination true
SET  pig.maxCombinedSplitSize 134217728

ld_DW_D_INSTALLATION_PRODUCTS = load '/dan/data/dwh/dw_d_installation_products' using PigStorage ('|') as (inst_prod_wid , bac_wid , district_code , billing_account_no , inst_sequence_no , product_code , contract_type , maintenance_contract , exchange_line_indicator , product_type , quantity , first_cph_date , last_cph_date , first_cph_term_expiry_date , last_cph_term_expiry_date , last_cph_order_no ,ts_last_updated , data_owner , source_system , etl_created_dt);
ld_DEDUP_PROD_TPC_EXTRACT = load '/dan/data/dedup/dedup_prod_tpc_extract' using PigStorage ('|') as ( productfamilyid , productfamily , productgroupid , productgroup , grouplobid , productgroupowninglob , newproductid , newproductname , productowner , lifecycleid , lifecycle , buildgroupid , buildgroupname , ukbreleaseno , gs_productbuildstatusid , gs_productbuildstatus , ab_code , ab_codename , codelobid , codeowninglob , ab_codedestinyid , ab_codedestiny , ab_code_treatmentid , ab_code_treatmentstatus , gs_mappingstatusid , gs_mappingstatus , consumercount , btb_count , gs_count , otherbu_count , operateflagid , operateflagdescription , withdrawalprojectid , withdrawalproject , line_type , note );
register 'hdfs:///usr/lib/pig/piggybank.jar'; 
define LENGTH org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.string.LENGTH();

//Some other stuff goes here
```